# how can i connect code to my local cockroachdb cluster using NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, database, cockroachdb

According to this tutorial, I created a local cockroachdb cluster with three nodes in the docker:

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.2/start-a-local-cluster-in-docker-windows

Now i try connect to this by postgresSQL

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client('postgresql://root@roach1:26257?sslmode=disable')
client.connect()
```

I've create new DB user through console named his as "ncado" and set "root" as password
Conection string create from this template:

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/connect-to-the-database.html

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client('postgresql://ncado:root@localhost:8080/messages.message?sslmode=verify-full&options=--cluster%3Droach1')
client.connect()
```

if i try change port to 26257, code throws error

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND roach1
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:72:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'roach1'
}
```

I've been testing my connection by this code:

```
app.post('/test', async (req,res)=>{
  const text = 'INSERT INTO messages.public.messag VALUES($1, $2,$3) RETURNING *'
  const values = [4, 'berserk',"HAI YAI FOOOORCES"]
  await client.query(text, values)
  res.send('done')

 
})
```

When i do request to that endpoint was starting endless "sending request"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 instances of cockroachdb running in docker in a cluster mode. Try to do the following:

1. Your connection string should be

```
postgresql://root@localhost:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable&options=--cluster%3Droach1
```

If you want to use the newly created Db user use this instead:

```
postgresql://ncado:root@localhost:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable&options=--cluster%3Droach1
```

`ncado` is the username and
`root` is the password

2. I think in the example they set ssl to - sslmode=verify-full. You won't be able to use ssl as you have not configured any certificates. Set leave it set to `disable`.
3. Port 8080 is the web interface which has the cockroach admin dashboard, you won't be able to make queries connecting to that port. The 26257 is where the is listening to TCP connections so your pg client should be connecting to that port.
4. The error you are seeing just means there are no DNS entries with roach1. Within the Docker network DNS will be able to resolve this address, outside it won't.
5. Try res.end() instead of res.send()